# Why can't we use square brackets in case of dynamic vectors?

Tags: c++, vector

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <vector>
#include <queue>

int main(){
   vector<int> *v = new vector<int>;
    v -> push_back(1);
    
    //min priority queue
    priority_queue<int, vector<int>, greater<int>> pq;

     pq.push(v[0]); //Able to do pq.push(v -> at(0))
}
```

So why is this giving an error? Am i not pushing an integer inside my priority queue?

Comment: `v` is (needlessly) a pointer. `v[0]` is deferencing that pointer. You're trying to push a `vector<int>` into a priority queue of `int`

Comment: dont allocate a vector dynamically. The vector does already dynamically allocate its elements, hence there is (almost) never a good reason for `new std::vector<int>;`

Comment: I'm literally unable to get it though. Why v[0] is a pointer. Isn't it *(&v + 0)?. So &v is the address of my integer vector. Than adding 0 it will be an address too(basically &v). And then de-referencing  this will actually point to the value..just like how arrays work

Comment: `v` is a pointer and `some_pointer[ index]` is exactly equivalent to `*( some_pointer + index)`

Comment: Right, so shouldn't this be the value at index 0th of this vector...after dereferencing?

Comment: @Aman pq.push will accept only a int as input. in your case v[0] will return a whole vector<int>. if you really want to use [] operator you can go with pq.push(v[0][0])

Comment: @Stoica Mircea, hey one last question and i'll leave. Why is v[0] a vector<int> and not int.

Comment: @Aman no. `* ( v + 0) == *(v) == *v` this is only dereferencing the pointer, not accessing elements of the vector

Comment: Like in case of dynamic arrays, if i write int *arr = new int; and then arr[0] that's actually the value at 0th index. Why is this not the case with vectors?

Comment: @Aman Now I understand your confusion ;). `std::vector` is not an array. `arr[0] == *( arr + 0) == *arr`. The first element has the same adress as the first element, hence dereferencign `arr` gets you the first element. Thats not the case for a `vector`

Comment: Exactly, do notice that i'm able to do pq.push(v -> at(0)). I've come to a conclusion of not using square brackets with a dynamic vector but to use the inbuilt functions like at() etc..

Comment: `operator[]` is completely fine to use with vectors. Your problem is that `v` is not a vector, it is a pointer to a vector.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A std vector already manages its buffer dynamically.

In 99.9% of cases, `new std::vector` is a mistake.

```
vector<int> v;
v.push_back(1);

//min priority queue
priority_queue<int, vector<int>, greater<int>> pq;

pq.push(v[0]);
```

this works.

If you are really in the 0.1% of cases where new on a vector makes sense, change `v[0]` to `(*v)[0]`.

What `v[0]` does is treat the pointer `v` as a pointer to an array of vectors. It then picks the 0th one.  It does not pick the 0th element of the 0th one.  `v[0][0]` would also work (but would be a bad way to do that when `v` is not actually a pointer to array; confusing to readers usually).

So C++ inherits an array pointer duality from C.  When you have a pointer, you can use square brackets to treat it as an array as if it was the pointer to the first element of the array.  This is actually how array `[]` works; the array is implicitly converted to a pointer, then `[]` applies.  This is confusing when you have a pointer that isn't pointing at an array.

C++ also has objects, and those objects can overload operators like square brackets.  The overloading happens on the objects *not* on pointers to those objects.

So `vector[]` fakes being an array and finds the elements owned by the vector.  `ptr_to_vector[]` insteat treats it as an array of vectors starting at `*ptr_to_vector`, almost never what you want.

C++ is relatively unique in having full fledged objects that can be values.  Few languages do.  This can be confusing if you are coming from other languages.  Embrance value semantics in C++ when you can.

Comment: `new std::vector is a mistake.` totally depends on the context. His question was why in this case his compiling is failing.

Comment: @StoicaMircea In the context of the question, and probably 99.9% of all the other contexts it's a mistake. As already mentioned in the answer. It does not *totally depend*.

Comment: @super in 99.99% is a mistake using vectors. Go and use array as follows : `int v[1] = {1};`. This is your answer. Nothing is a mistake when you know what you are doing.

Answer (score 3):

This will fix your compile

```
pq.push((*v)[0]);
```

Since v is pointer to a `vector<int>`.

In this case `pq.push` will accept only an int as input. `v[0]` will return a `vector<int>` object. If you really want to use [] index operator you can go with `pq.push(v[0][0])`

Reworked code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <vector>
#include <queue>

int main(){
    vector<int> *v = new vector<int>;
    v -> push_back(1);
    
    //min priority queue
    priority_queue<int, vector<int>, greater<int>> pq;

    pq.push((*v)[0]);
    delete v; // don't forget.
}
```

Comment: It will make the compile error go away but is not a good fix to the issue - see the other answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/69405441/151019

Comment: Come on. He wanted to know why his compile is failing, no other workarounds....

@mmmmmm
See the question `So why is this giving an error? Am i not pushing an integer inside my priority queue?`

Comment: To answer that I would say the error is that you are using new on a vector - fix that line

Comment: @mmmmmm look again to my answer. Where's the problem?? Let's not using pointers because they are complicated, right? He'll have to deal with pointers at some point, better learn from now than spending hours in figure out how to fix the compile..

Comment: That’s a poor excuse for not calling out a bad practice. There are going to be plenty of legitimate needs for pointers where OP can learn about them. `new`ing a Standard Library container is *very* likely not one. Let’s not encourage anti-patterns.

Comment: @sweenish Indeed for this example that's a bad practice, but this is another topic. The guy who posted this question didn't asked for a good practice. He asked why the compiling is failing.

Comment: It’s possible to cover both, you know.